# 'Failed to generate reports view' error in JBehave

Tags: java, maven, bdd, jbehave

While running JBehave BDD scenarios I get this error:

```
Generating reports view to 'C:\Users\dev\.hudson\jobs\JavaProject\workspace\behavioural-test\target\jbehave' using formats '[stats, console, ide_console]' and view properties '{viewDirectory=view, views=ftl/jbehave-views.ftl, reports=ftl/jbehave-reports-with-totals.ftl, decorateNonHtml=true, nonDecorated=ftl/jbehave-report-non-decorated.ftl, decorated=ftl/jbehave-report-decorated.ftl, defaultFormats=stats, maps=ftl/jbehave-maps.ftl}'
Failed to generate reports view to 'C:\Users\dev\.hudson\jobs\JavaProject\workspace\behavioural-test\target\jbehave' using formats '[stats, console, ide_console]' and view properties '{viewDirectory=view, views=ftl/jbehave-views.ftl, reports=ftl/jbehave-reports-with-totals.ftl, decorateNonHtml=true, nonDecorated=ftl/jbehave-report-non-decorated.ftl, decorated=ftl/jbehave-report-decorated.ftl, defaultFormats=stats, maps=ftl/jbehave-maps.ftl}'
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.531 sec <<< FAILURE!
```

All the scenarios pass, but for afew it shows 'Failed to generate reports.... Errors: 1' (not failures)

How to fix this? Or what changes do I have to do in configuration to suppress these errors?